# Bash Script working on Tumbleweed but not Kubuntu

Tags: bash, openssl

We have a virtual Dev-Environment in which we develop a multitude of websites.
We have some scripts that we use to create the environment, one of which handles the creation of the Certificates and pushing them to certain directories.
Said script works for my colleague, who uses Tumbleweed, but not for me (Kubuntu 22.04, Kernel 5.15)

The script is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p cert/live/exist.ulb.tu-darmstadt.de
mkdir -p cert/live/purl.ulb.tu-darmstadt.de
mkdir -p cert/live/tueditions.ulb.tu-darmstadt.de

cd cert

openssl req \
    -x509 \
    -nodes \
    -new \
    -sha256 \
    -days 1024 \
    -newkey rsa:2048 \
    -keyout ${CertAUTH}.key \
    -out    ${CertAUTH}.pem \
    -subj "/C=DE/CN=Example-Root-CA"

openssl x509 \
    -outform pem \
    -in  ${CertAUTH}.pem \
    -out ${CertAUTH}.crt

openssl req \
    -outform pem \
    -new \
    -nodes \
    -newkey rsa:2048 \
    -keyout privkey.pem \
    -out localhost.csr \
    -subj "/C=DE/ST=HE/L=Darmstadt/O=ULB/CN=*.localhost"

openssl x509 \
    -outform pem \
    -req \
    -sha256 \
    -days 1024 \
    -in localhost.csr \
    -CA    ${CertAUTH}.pem \
    -CAkey ${CertAUTH}.key \
    -CAcreateserial \
    -extfile domains.ext \
    -out fullchain.pem
    

cp fullchain.pem live/exist.ulb.tu-darmstadt.de
cp fullchain.pem live/purl.ulb.tu-darmstadt.de
cp fullchain.pem live/tueditions.ulb.tu-darmstadt.de

cp privkey.pem live/exist.ulb.tu-darmstadt.de
cp privkey.pem live/purl.ulb.tu-darmstadt.de
cp privkey.pem live/tueditions.ulb.tu-darmstadt.de

cd ..
```

The script is supposed to create directories and create fullchain.pem files, yyou can probably get what it should do.My output is the following:

```
Can't open "domains.ext" for reading, No such file or directory
4047A01AD37F0000:error:80000002:system library:BIO_new_file:No such file or directory:../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:67:calling fopen(domains.ext, r)
4047A01AD37F0000:error:10000080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:75:
cp: Aufruf von stat für 'fullchain.pem' nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
cp: Aufruf von stat für 'fullchain.pem' nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
cp: Aufruf von stat für 'fullchain.pem' nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

nota bene: we have pre-created the domains.ext as current user and entered the necessary information.We're clueless what's happening here, maybe somebody here has a solution for me/us?

all the best

Comment: My guess is that `domains.etc` isn't under the `cert` directory that you `cd` to in your script. That's based on `cd cert` and `openssl ... -extfile domains.ext ...` in your script and the first error message `Can't open "domains.ext" for reading, No such file or directory`

Comment: Ah, sorry. I wrote "We have pre-created the domains.ext" in the .. directory, as we feared this would be an issue :-D However, didn't change the output. I should've been clearer on that one, though...

Comment: You said `We have pre-created the domains.ext` but you didn't say `We have pre-created the domains.ext in the cert directory under the directory from which I'm running this script`. I still think that's your problem, if not - beats me. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cp` errors are because the script didn't exit after failing the create the previous dependency. Add `set -e -o pipefail` the top to prevent the script from proceeding after an error.

Next, the `domains.ext` isn't in the correct location. At the top, your allowing `mkdir` to fail silently with the `-p` argument:

```
-p, --parents
              no error if existing, make parent directories as needed
```

Meaning that it likely created the cert dir too, which is where your script was expecting to find the domains.ext. You can confirm this by testing for your prerequsits first, exiting with a sane failure if it's missing. This is what I would add to the top of the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e -o pipefail
[[ -f cert/domains.ext ]] || { echo 'ERROR: ./cert/domains.ext is missing' ; exit 1 ; }
```